# Hpple Element returning with null content

Tags: html, ios, iphone, xpath, hpple

I am trying to parse HTML using an Xpath query string (in Objective-C for iOS). I'm grabbing the element I want, but with everything *except* the contents.

Example html:

```
<textarea type="text" name="name" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"/>Contents</textarea>
```

My attempt to grab the element:

```
TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:response];
NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//textarea[@name='name']";
NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];
```

NSLog of the element in the nodes array:

```
nodeAttributeArray =     (
            {
        attributeName = type;
        nodeContent = text;
    },
            {
        attributeName = name;
        nodeContent = name;
    },
            {
        attributeName = style;
        nodeContent = "width: 100px; height:100px;";
    }
);
nodeName = textarea;
raw = "<textarea type=\"text\" name=\"name\" style=\"width: 100px; height:100px;\"></textarea>";
}
```

No contents. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well `<textarea type="text" name="name" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"/>` is an empty element as the trailing `/>` closes the tag, at least in X(HT)ML syntax. On the other hand, pure XML parsing would then give an error on the `</textarea>` that follows.

Comment: Okay I see that now. So is this a problem with what I am trying to parse or how am I trying to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a case of bad html. The tag self closes but also has a separate closing tag.

Should like like this:

```
<textarea type="text" name="name" style="width: 100px; height:100px;">Contents</textarea>
```